# Angular ui-grid : Method injected inside header of data grid is being called for each data cell rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Method injected inside header of data grid is being called for each data cell rendering and also being called when we do horizontal or vertical scroll . For reproducing this issue i have attached plnkr link here .
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZW43LsiLY7GdnX6XEOgG?p=preview ,
http://plnkr.co/edit/3E8HTz4Z2daGqRh1WHtx?p=preview
 (`<div class="ui-grid-top-panel"  style="text-align: center">{{grid.appScope.letter()}}</div>`

 , try sorting , horizontal or vertical scroll ).

For instance : Below is header cell view template, we have `injected {{ grid.appScope.getHeaderLetter( col.name, $parent.$index )}}` and when we do horizontal or vertical scroll or at the time of initial cell rendering getHeaderLetter method is being called for each data cell. In another words if we have 100000 cells then method is being called 100000 times. I think I am missing some important fact in terms of use cases . I would highly appreciate your comment on this.

----Header Definition----

```
<div class="ui-grid-top-panel ui-grid-top-panel-single" id="{{'ui-grid-index-' + col.name  }}" style="text-align: center">
  <div class="ui-grid-alphbet ui-grid-alphbet-first">{{ grid.appScope.getHeaderLetter( col.name, $parent.$index ) }}
  </div>
     .
     .
     .
     more code
```

I have asked the same question here ... https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4250, but didn't got any reply.

Comment: This behaviour is not specific to ui-grid, but to the abuse of angular templates: the `{{i=i+1}}` creates a binding that changes the bound value every time it is computed, thus leading to a new digest cycle indefinitely. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bj78xmej/) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos but i'm getting the same behavior when i'm injecting method inside the template.. can u add more, how should i handle this situation ? how can i call a method inside those curly braces , so that it doesn't get called multiple times ?

Comment: The "curly braces" represent one-way bindings. These expressions are called on each digest cycle by design.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos i have updated the plnkr , still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the way angular dirty-checking works. not much you can do about it. just try not to put long-running operations in such functions.

how about this:

```
  $scope.letterFn = function () {
    console.log("CHANGE LETTER")
    return i;
  }

  $scope.letter = $scope.letterFn();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/yF1sSG2QXeO9cFNAeDYm?p=preview

Comment: awesome .. it works. But how?? Can you plz explain in bit details.

Comment: so, angular runs a bunch of digest cycles. how many really depends on what is going on on the page. it's a big topic,just google "angular digest" for more info. so, each cycle it would try to evaluate all bindings. to evaluate your {{grid.letter()}} angular has to call the function each time. what i did is simply replaced it with a variable. so value of the variable is calculated once, but retrieved multiple times, because we didn't do anything about the number of digest cycles to render the page.